# svg gage created_at logic

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, svg

I've just started exploring using svgs within rails. I want to dynamically update a [gagejs](http://justgage.com/) with the created_at column on my Comment model.

Is this possible? For example, if the user hasn't created a comment in x amount of time the gage drops randomly between a certain range. It sounds like a fun problem to solve, i just would like to know that it is indeed solvable.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [setTimeout](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/using-settimeout-javascript/) to run something after a delay and [DOM](http://www.carto.net/svg/manipulating_svg_with_dom_ecmascript/) to update things dynamically. The links give you some examples of each so you'd just need to tie them together.